# strange habit of setInterval every interval is one time behind schadual javacsript jQuery

Tags: javascript, setinterval, delay

I beleive set interval() in javascript must work
for the moment of that interval .. but in my test
every interval out puts the previous interval data

setTimeout() works correct .. on every page refresh

function bellow on client mobile gets a date from
remote server geven in a div ..
the anser on setTimeout() is nearlly correct and time
on server and client are the same ..
cant see why anwers from setInterval() are always one
interval behind ..

```
    <script>
    var href = 'https://some-domain.com';   
    function check_time() {         
    $('#timestamp_far').load(''+href+' #timestamp_far');

    setTimeout(function () { 
        element_stamp = document.getElementById('timestamp_far'); 
        stamp_ne = element_stamp.innerText;
        alert(stamp_ne); 
    }, 500);

    } // end check_time     

    setInterval(check_time, 30*1000);
    setTimeout(check_time, 500);
    </script>

    // remote sever 
    <?php 
    $date_now_server = date('i:s');
    ?>
    <div id="timestamp_far"> <?php echo $date_now_server; ?></div>


// for example observed are:
now client 10:10
setTimeout 10:12 // internet delay, ookay
setInterval nothing 

now client 10:40
setTimeout 10:45 // internet delay, ookay
setInterval 10:12 // alway shows previous time
```

how can I get correct fresh data in setInterval as
setTimeout is always correct, in javascript / jQuery ?
really thanks in advance ..

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, `setInterval()` is correctly fired every 500 milliseconds. https://jsfiddle.net/sqf9jvud/

Answer (score 0):

found answer to my own question , I think when post question here kind of high imagination loads to myself and some times find the answer hhh ..

problem is the delay of first interval, if its too fast then link below cant get data on this time interval ..

```
$('#timestamp_far').load(''+href+' #timestamp_far');
```

but after a second or so gets the answer and keeps it for next interval .. so reset with use of line bellow not use the previous data ..

```
element_stamp =  document.getElementById('timestamp_far').innerHTML = "";
```

finally set the timeOut insdie the function to enough long so that faunktion has enough time to get data ..

```
}, 500); to something more like }, 1500);
```